# MYSQL with table join on query（Could the query works more efficient?）

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join, self-join

I've two tables, the users:

[image]

and the scores of exercise of the users, `paperId` shows the exercise ID, and the `firstTry` shows if it is the first try (value 0) or not (others value):

[image]

For a given classroom (e.g. classrootm=1), I want to query the **max** exercise score of everyone with the `classroom=1`, even if the user did not finish the exercise (like the man called 欧阳锋).

[image]

My query sequence is:

```
select u.*, s.* from users u
left join
(
    select s.*
    from (                
        select uid, max(score) as score, max(firstTry) as times
        from scores
        where paperId = 25 
        group by uid
    ) t, scores s
    where
    s.paperId = 25
    AND s.uid = t.uid AND s.score = t.score AND s.firstTry = t.times
) s
on s.uid = u.uid
where classroom = 1
ORDER BY s.score DESC, s.id ASC
```

Could it be more simple? or how to write the `mysql` sequence to make the query works more efficient? It seems my query joins table three times

The code and demo go here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a415566/8

Comment: In your query you seem to get no results if the user had a better score in the first try than the second (see result for "杨过" [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbd639/1), I just changed the first result to 96). Is it a bug or an intended behavior? To be more precise, do you want to query the `firstTry` value associated to the better score, or just want to know if the user has tried more than once even if the better score was on the first try?

Comment: Yes, that's a bug! I just want to select the max score of the users different tries. But if I don't use `max(firstTry)`, there will be another bug if one had the same score with  different records (e.g. 杨过 has two score 94)

Comment: one with the same score in different records, causes the duplicate records in the query result, that's http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a415566/9

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to outer join the best score row per classroom-1 user. The best method to do this is probably a lateral join:

```
SELECT u.*, s.* 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(
  SELECT *
  FROM scores sc
  WHERE sc.paperId = 25 
  AND sc.uid = u.uid 
  ORDER BY sc.score DESC, sc.firstTry DESC
  LIMIT 1
) s ON true
WHERE u.classroom = 1
ORDER BY s.score DESC, s.id ASC;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/1LwG92h4

Docs on lateral joins in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html

Comment: It's awesome! let me working on `Lateral Join`

Comment: So, without using `LATERAL` the way the OP made it originally is the only way to pass the `only_full_group_by` error? I'm funnily working on a similar request right now :D To be more precise I mean a sub-subrequest selecting only the max value with the group by, and the join on the subrequest that selects rows with this max value and limit 1?

Comment: @Kaddath: No, apart from lateral joins the typical way to get the top n rows per group is to use `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` to rank the rows and only keep the best ranked rows. I've added such a query to my demo here: https://dbfiddle.uk/abIiMy_O

Comment: @Kaddath: And as to `only_full_group_by`: Consider this a must. Always have this mode set in MySQL. Otherwise you work in a cheat mode where the DBMS allows invalid aggregation queries leading to results you might not expect instead of telling you what is wrong with your query. The mode was the default in old MySQL versions and luckily isn't anymore in new ones. If you are running MySQL in cheat mode, this may indicate that you are working with an outdated MySQL version, in which case you should upgrade.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes we are already kind of transitionning, I work on an old version locally while we switched to mariaDb in production, I'll take a look how mariaDb behaves about this. Note that usually we mind which row is kept but there may be still be cases we group to remove row duplication in edge cases it was easier than to remove a left join